# WSO2 ESB Unit Test Suite - problem with artifact from registry

Tags: unit-testing, wso2, wso2-esb

WSO2:    7.0.0

WSO2 MI: 1.1.0

I have defined Unit Test Suite for sequence with Validation Mediator. Validator mediator uses json schema from Registry (conf:schema/PostQuestionsJSONSchema.json):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="ValidateUpdateQuestion" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <validate cache-schema="true">
        <schema key="conf:schema/PostQuestionsJSONSchema.json"/>
        <on-fail>
            <propertyGroup description="Set Error Info">
                <property name="httpErrorCode" scope="default" type="STRING" value="400"/>
                <property name="httpErrorMessage" scope="default" type="STRING" value="Bad Request"/>
            </propertyGroup>
            <sequence key="DefaultFaultHandler"/>
        </on-fail>
    </validate>
</sequence>
```

In my Unit Test Suite, I have defined registry-resource (PostQuestionsJSONSchema.json):

```
<unit-test>
    <artifacts>
        <test-artifact>
            <artifact>/TestProject/src/main/synapse-config/sequences/ValidateUpdateQuestion.xml</artifact>
        </test-artifact>
        <supportive-artifacts>
            <artifact>/TestProject/src/main/synapse-config/sequences/DefaultFaultHandler.xml</artifact>
        </supportive-artifacts>
        <registry-resources>
            <registry-resource>
                <file-name>PostQuestionsJSONSchema.json</file-name>
                <artifact>\TestProjectRegistry\PostQuestionsJSONSchema.json</artifact>
                <registry-path>/_system/config/schema</registry-path>
                <media-type>application/json</media-type>
            </registry-resource>
        </registry-resources>
        <connector-resources/>
    </artifacts>
    <test-cases>
        <test-case name="valid">
            <input>
                <payload><![CDATA[<body></body>]]></payload>
                <properties>
                    <property name="Content-Type" scope="transport" value="application/json"/>
                </properties>
            </input>
            <assertions>
                <assertNotNull>
                    <actual>$body</actual>
                    <message>Body is NULL</message>
                </assertNotNull>
            </assertions>
        </test-case>
    </test-cases>
    <mock-services/>
</unit-test>
```

But when I start that test, I have:

```
[INFO] +-------------------+----------------+---------------+---------------+
[INFO] |   TEST CASE       |   DEPLOYMENT   |   MEDIATION   |   ASSERTION   |
[INFO] +===================+================+===============+===============+
[INFO] | Test Case - Suite |    PASSED      |    FAILED     |    SKIPPED    |
[INFO] +-------------------+----------------+---------------+---------------+
[INFO] 
[INFO] Failed Test Case(s): 
[INFO] +-------------------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[INFO] |   TEST CASE       |   FAILURE STATE   |       EXCEPTION / ERROR MESSAGE                                                           |
[INFO] +===================+===================+===========================================================================================+
[INFO] | Test Case - valid |    MEDIATION      | No Schema is available with the key  : conf:schema/PostQuestionsJSONSchema.json           |
[INFO] |                   |                   | org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.ValidateMediator.mediate(ValidateMediator.java:413)  |
```

How to define correclty registry resources for Unit Test Suite?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this in the latest WSO2 MI 1.2.0 runtime? They have done a couple of fixes for the unit testing framework. It worked for me the unit test suite with both registry and connector resources.

Comment: On WSO2 MI 1.2.0 I have still problem, but thje error message is diferent:

` Error creating a new schema objects for schemas : [Value {name ='null', keyValue ='conf:schema/PostQuestionsJSONSchema.json'}]
 org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator.handleException(AbstractMediator.java:376)
 org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.ValidateMediator.mediate(ValidateMediator.java:450)org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
 org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java`